# flex or flex-grow, flex-grow or flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i am using a flex to adjust a width for these element;  main, .aside1, .aside2. a page comes as i expected.
as i know flex is a shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis.
because a first shorthand for a flex is a flex-grow, so i try to change a flex to flex-grow to make width adjustment for some elements hoping it will give a same results, but  a results are not  as expected.

The code with 'flex'

```css
.container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 800px;
}

section
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;   
}

section > *
{
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

main
{
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
    background-color: tomato;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.aside1
{
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.aside2
{
    flex: 1;
    order: 3;
    background-color: mediumorchid;
    text-align: center;
}

footer
{
    order: 4;
    background-color: teal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox Lagi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">   
        <section>
            <main>           
                 <h1>Main</h1>
            </main>

            <aside class="aside1">
                <h1>Aside1</h1>
            </aside>

            <aside class="aside2">
                <h1>Aside2</h1>
            </aside>

            <footer>
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </footer>

        </section>

    </div><!--endContainer-->
</body>
</html>
```

i change flex with flex-grow https://i.ibb.co/PrbZdXg/flexeded.png

this is how it looks when a flex change to flex-grow:
[image: how it looks when flex is changed to flex-grow]

why flex-grow doesn't work as it should

instead using a shorthand 'flex', to make same output for scalling an element . i prefer using a flex-grow. so, i'm not confuse by a shorthand order

i also tried a simple code line for a flex-grow.
in this line a flex-grow is going well

```css
.container
    {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: grey;
        width: 800px;
    }
    
    .box1
    {
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: green;
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 30px;
        
    }
    
    .box2
    {
        flex-grow: 2;
        background-color: red;
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .box3
    {
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>flex or flex-grow</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1">A</div>
        <div class="box2">B</div>
        <div class="box3">C</div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code & images in the question, rather than linking to external resources. This is especially important in case of your question being useful in the future to others, but the external resources no longer being available.

Comment: And it's not clear to me from your question what code you are changing. Are you simply replacing every single `flex` with `flex-grow`? Or are you writing `flex: 1; flex-grow: whatever` to override just the shorthand? Are you only changing some of them?

Comment: @Reed thanks for a suggestion and info. i've added a new description in a question

Answer (score 3):

If you're only changing `flex` to `flex-grow`, then I think you lose the implicit properties for `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`. If you inspect the elements & view the CSS property, you can see the implicit properties from the shorthand.

So if you'r ejust changing `flex:2` to `flex-grow:2`, you'll need to also declare the `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` (or so I think)

[image: inspect-element view with flex shorthand expanded into flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis]

Comment: In other case, i actually do an another code for a flex-grow. a flex-grow is a flex-grow. "free" from the other two flex, flex-shrink and flex-basis

Comment: So did you try putting `flex-grow: 2; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis:0%;`? Or is the only flex-property `flex-grow:2`?

Comment: yes, i did as you suggested. I did putting all three flex: flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex- basis. It's work. but why in a simple code line a flex-grow is "free" from the others (flex- shrink and flex-basis). i put a description bout this in a question

Comment: It's a bit beyond me. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) say `a <number>: In this case it is interpreted as flex: <number> 1 0; the <flex-shrink> value is assumed to be 1 and the <flex-basis> value is assumed to be 0.` [The W3C Standards on Flex](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) might have more information detailing why it works that way.

Comment: i think you were right about the implicit of flex. flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis seems relating on each other. it's 'safer' using a flex shorthand instead, i think

Comment: You absolutely ARE correct about the implicit values being absent. This can actually burn you in some cases, if one declares using the aggregate (shortcut) properties in one location, and then uses just the specific property in another, higher specificity or not. Consider the following html: `hello<br>world
<div>hello<br>world</div>` styled by the following css: `body {font-size:100px; font-family:system-ui; line-height:2;} div { font:100px system-ui; }`. You'd think they'd be identical. They're not. The use of the font aggregate selector overwrites the line-height. This is the same principle

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this

```
flex: 1 0 100%
```

first parameter is flex-grow

second parameter is flex-shrink

third parameter is flex-basis

Comment: i don't really like a shorthand for a flex. anyway thanks for a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

i know what's actually happens with my code.
i tried to change this line `section > * {flex-basis: 100%;}` with `section > * { flex-basis: 200px;}`.
changing `main {flex-grow: 7;}`
changing `footer {flex-basis: 800px;}`

at last, a flex-grow work as it should.
thanks for everyone for giving their time to answer my question